# Baked light dark, not changing when I change intensity

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I have a scene with a static object with a standard material and 1 directional light marked as baked.

The problem I have is that changing the intensity of the light does absolutely nothing, when I increment the light intensity, while the light is baking I can see the object brighter, but when it finishes baking then it looks the same as before (dark).

I have tried changing the baking to manual to see if that could be a problem but the result is exactly the same.

My lighting settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMwvW.jpg

My object settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fggGB.jpg

My light settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmTUU.jpg

My object when intensity = 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKjfW.jpg

My object when intensity = 8 https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTTO8.jpg (it looks a little bit different but i think it is because I changed the perspective.

This is not the first time I run into this problem, please I must be doing something wrong.